# What am I doing wrong with my math?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of fatalities and populations that I need to normalize to fatalities per 100K people:

```
CREATE TABLE all_states (
  state character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  fatalities integer NOT NULL,
  population integer NOT NULL
);
```

I want to calculate the fatality rate per 100,000 people, so I did:

```
SELECT *, (fatalities/population)*100000 AS rate 
FROM all_states;
```

But what I get is just 0s:

```
STATE          population   fatalities  rate
"Alabama"      4802740      75          0
"Alaska"       722718       39          0
"Arizona"      6482505      69          0
"Arkansas"     2937979      93          0
"California"   37691912     390         0
```

I feel like I'm missing something super simple here. I tried casting it as a float but that didn't change the results:

```
SELECT state, population, fatalities, 
       CAST(((fatalities/population)*100000) AS float) AS rate 
FROM all_states;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that / operator in integer division truncates the result, check  [Mathematical Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-math.html)

Try with:

```
SELECT *,(fatalities::float/population)*100000 AS rate FROM all_states;
```

Or

```
SELECT *,(fatalities::numeric/population)*100000 AS rate FROM all_states;
```

Comment: Also: `100000.0 * fatalities / population AS rate`